# Who is Minho named after?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In the Maze Runner book,(spoiler alert!!) Thomas finds out that their names aren't their real ones, but they are named after some clever people.

Like Thomas is named after Edison, Alby after Einstein, Newt after Isaac Newton etc.

Do we know who is Minho named after? I tried googling, but all I got was some Korean rapper

Comment: Minho is also the name of a northern region of Portugal. But I don't think it is related with the Maze runner story.

Comment: @NunoFreitas and more importantly, the river in Spain that gives its name to that region :-p

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this interview with James Dashner](http://www.ourtimeinjuvie.com/author-spotlight/author-spotlight-interview-with-james-dashner-part-i):

> People always ask me who Minho was named after. Well, I purposely did that: because the story is set pretty far in the future, I wanted to have at least one or two names that we don’t know, so it’s someone who doesn’t exist yet.

---

The URL where I found the interview with James Dashner now points to a missing page. However [I found a copy of the old page on the Wayback Machine site](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307051032/http://www.ourtimeinjuvie.com/author-spotlight-interview-with-james-dashner-part-i/). I'm concerned this link may rot too, but I don't want to list the whole interview for fear of copyright infringement. However I'll post the full text of the section where Dashner is asked about the names:

> **Jenny: Okay, so changing subjects a little bit, let’s talk names. Everyone has a historic names: Thomas Edison, Isaac Newton… with Theresa Agnes, I was guessing Mother Theresa. Is that right?**
>   Yep.
>   **Jenny: Cool! So what’s the significance of all the names?**
>   The thing with the names is there really is no significance to them. The reason it’s important is that I wanted to show the creators, the people who started this process, they thought that by almost dehumanizing [the candidates], by taking away their real names and giving them nicknames, it would create a separation between them, make it seem less real that you’re doing this to kids. What name they were given doesn’t have anything to do with their personality or the plans for them. People always ask me who Minho was named after. Well, I purposely did that: because the story is set pretty far in the future, I wanted to have at least one or two names that we don’t know, so it’s someone who doesn’t exist yet.

Comment: There's of course tvtropes page for it EinsteinNewtonSurak, also know as Famous Famous Fictional http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FamousFamousFictional?from=Main.NewtonEinsteinSurak

Answer (score 1):

Minho was named after James Dashner's nieces's husband. His name was Minho. Ki Hong Lee said this in one of his interviews on youtube for evidence.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a link to the interview?

Answer (score 0):

I thought Minho was just a name to throw people off course and make us think that Tommy was lying, like the wicked people named most of them after some brilliant people, but if someone found out and they realized it was probably going to be Thomas so they made to people randomly. So they would think Thomas was a liar.

Comment: I don't follow, can you clarify what "*Realized it was prob going to be Thomas so the made to people randomly*" menas?

Answer (score -3):

My father thought that Minho was named for Mendelssohn the man who discovered recessive genes. I thought that was a good guess.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  That is an interesting theory, but do you have any supporting evidence to aid your answer; production notes may be useful in this answer.

Comment: Fan theories are interesting, but we typically prefer answers that are based on some sort of canon source

Comment: [Mendelssohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Mendelssohn) was a composer. It was [Gregor Mendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Mendel) who did the early work in genetics.

Answer (score -3):

I think that Minho stands for King Minos and the Minotaur, from th greek mythology, because the story is in a labyrinth too...

Comment: It's an interesting and clever theory, but if you had read the accepted answer, it's supposedly named after someone who has not lived yet. (Also, the others were all real people, not mythological characters.)

Answer (score -3):

The author of the books mentions that he wanted to make some names that would throw people off, but now, there’s a crazy famous Korean rapper with the name Minho. It’s like he foretold the future. But when I saw the interview, his neice’s husband’s name.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question - the author didn’t actually name him after this rapper.